# Create array with dynamic key - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do this:

```
var array = [];

array[1] = {
    'name': 'Raul'
};

array[5] = {
    'name': 'Ilidio'
};

array[20] = {
    'name': 'Ferreira'
};

array[1001] = {
    'name': 'Reis'
};

console.log(array);
```

When I run `console.log()` this appears:

[image]

I want only the keys that I defined to appear. Am I doing something wrong to give me all the keys up to 1001?

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties): _When setting a property on a JavaScript array when the property is a valid array index and that index is outside the current bounds of the array, the engine will update the array's length property accordingly_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what an array *is* - it sounds like you want an object:

```js
var obj = {};

obj[1] = {
    'name': 'Raul'
};

obj[5] = {
    'name': 'Ilidio'
};

obj[20] = {
    'name': 'Ferreira'
};

obj[1001] = {
    'name': 'Reis'
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!